# How do I control an upper limit on a global variable?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I want to control the amount of energy that goes into the system. Each turtle has its own set amount and I have an estimate of what the total average should be.

However, in my current code, the energy always exceeds this amount, often by a lot. I don't mind that this occurs occasionally but I'd like it to average out at each run of the model.

It's the line `while [sum [energy] of turtles < 1752]` that I'm trying to use to limit the energy.

```
globals [energy]

breed[ones one]
breed[twos two]
breed[threes three]
breed[fours four]
breed[fives five]
breed[sixes six]
breed[sevens seven]

to setup
clear-all
ask patches [
    while [sum [energy] of turtles < 1752] [
let choose-size random-float 1
  if choose-size < 0.493 [ sprout-ones 1 ]
  if choose-size >= 0.493 and choose-size < 0.861 [ sprout-twos 1 set energy 75 ]
  if choose-size >= 0.861 and choose-size < 0.921 [ sprout-threes 1 set energy 216 ]
  if choose-size >= 0.921 and choose-size < 0.988 [ sprout-fours 1 set energy 700]
  if choose-size >= 0.988 and choose-size < 0.994 [ sprout-fives 1 set energy 2500]
  if choose-size >= 0.994 and choose-size < 0.998 [ sprout-sixes 1 set energy 8500]
  if choose-size >= 0.998  [ sprout-sevens 1 set energy 25000]

]]
  
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `while` in your code. `While` means that the code will be repeated until the condition is no longer valid. This means that the first patch will keep sprouting turtles until the limit is exceeded, and all other patches will not sprout any turtles at all.

```
ask patches [
    while [sum [energy] of turtles < 1752] [
    <...>
    ]
]
```

If you replace your `while` with an `if` instead, each patch will only try once to sprout a turtle. At that point, the total number of turtles that could be sprouted is dependent on the number of patches that you have.

Comment: It might also be appropriate to `while [sum ... < 1752] [ ask patches [ ... ] ]`, depending on the desired logic

Comment: Just getting back to this now. I can't do a straight swap of `while` for `if` because then the following block is expecting a true/false statement. And @SethTisue, if I try your code I get turtles on every patch with the energy far exceeding my limit of 1752.

Comment: re "I can't do a straight swap of while for if", note that `if` and `while` have different syntax. `while` takes square brackets, `if` does not. see NetLogo Dictionary. conceptually, `if` takes a single boolean as input, always evaluated exactly once, whereas `while` takes a boolean condition that it will evaluate 1 or more times.

Comment: re: the bigger picture here, it sounds to me like you aren't really clear on precisely what logic you are trying to implement.